# How can I extend my Ubuntu Linux partition to the left without breaking UEFI boot?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

[image]

- I have an Ubuntu Linux partition `/dev/nvme0n1p5` that I wish to extend to the left.
- On the other side, I also have a Windows partition `/dev/nvme0n1p3` that has been shrunk for that reason.

I'm afraid that if I extend the Ubuntu partition to the left that the GRUB boot will be broken. How can I safely extend this Ubuntu partition to the left?

Comment: This will not break Grub. But you should have good backups, just for the case something goes wrong like a power outage. It will need long time, all data in the partition will be moved, so be patient.

Comment: Then how does the system initially knows where to point when booting then ? Grub needs to be stored somewhere, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't have a problem resizing the partition. Grub is on one of the smaller partition .

If you can manage it I'd recommend getting a second drive and have Windows on one drive and Ubuntu on the other.

1 TB SSD are less then $100 US.

Comment: The OP already has a NVMe 1TB drive, more than enough for half a dozen OSes, let alone just Ubuntu + Windows. And depending on the price it can make a lot more sense to invest in a slower yet larger for cheaper HDD drive to have with a data partition (NTFS) to be shared by both OSes and contain personal files / multimedia, etc.

Comment: What do you mean that GRUB is on one of the smaller partition ? I'm not asking about having a second drive. If I could, I would already have. I'm on a ultrabook with a single slot for NVMe drive, so that's not even possible.